# formal description of TM that on input x computes the next word in the lexicographic order

Tags: computation-theory

For Σ = {0, 1}, give a formal description of a TM M that on input x computes the next word in Σ∗ according to the lexicographic order.
For example, on input 11, M halts with 000 on its tape

Answer (score 0):

We will design a single-tape deterministic Turing machine to compute the next word in lexicographic order given a word w on the tape. Here is our strategy:

1. scan to the end of input and see if the least significant bit is equal to 0. If so, increment it, and be done.
2. otherwise, scan left until you see a 0, in which case you increment it and then halt. keep looking until you reach the front of the tape.
3. if you got here, your input is of the form 11...1 and you need to replace all 1s but the first with 0s and then add an extra 0 on the end. To accomplish this, scan right until you find the first blank, replacing all 1s you see with 0s; then, replace exactly one blank with a 0, then halt.

Here are the transitions and states:

```
state   tape    state'    tape'    direction    comment

q0      blank   halt-acc  0        same         assume 0 for empty tape
q0      0,1     q1        0,1      right        scan right

q1      blank   q2        blank    left         go to LSB
q1      0,1     q0        0,1      right        scan to end of input

q2      blank   q3        1        right        input is 11...1
q2      0       halt-acc  1        same         found the least significant 0
q2      1       q2        1        left         keep looking

q3      blank   halt-acc  0        same         ran out of tape, add one 0
q3      0       halt-rej  0        same         this transition cannot happen
q3      1       q3        0        right        replace all but 1st 1 with 0
```